# Is this a theorem (is it correct?)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

My instruction notes have specified a theorem of matrix transpose that be there two compatible matrices $A$ and $B$ in respect of their sums and products, then:

$(AB)^T =A^TB^T$

So I set on to verify if indeed this is correct:

Let $A = \begin{pmatrix}2 & 2 \\ 6 & 4\end{pmatrix}  $

Let $B = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 7 & 3\end{pmatrix}  $

$A^T=\begin{pmatrix}2 & 6 \\ 2 & 4\end{pmatrix}  $

$B^T=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 7 \\ 0 & 3\end{pmatrix}  $

$(AB) = \begin{pmatrix}2 & 6 \\ 2 & 4\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 7 \\ 0 & 3\end{pmatrix}$=$\begin{pmatrix}16 & 6 \\ 34 & 12\end{pmatrix}  $

hence $(AB)^T=\begin{pmatrix}16 & 34 \\ 6 & 12\end{pmatrix}$

and....
$A^TB^T=\begin{pmatrix}2 & 6 \\ 2 & 4\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 7 \\ 0 & 3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2 & 32 \\ 2 & 26\end{pmatrix}$

$\therefore (AB)^T\neq A^TB^T $

Is the theorem wrong or am having a rough time understanding?

Comment: The $\alpha$ has to be a *scalar* (i.e. a number). For matrices, $(AB)^T = B^TA^T$.

Comment: @mrf, sorry I got mixed up on the theorem. The correct one has been specified.

Comment: As I already said, it should be $(AB)^T = B^TA^T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assertion is false; what is true is that
$$
(AB)^T=B^TA^T
$$
which can be easily proved. Actually, the product $A^TB^T$ need not be defined when the product $AB$ is defined, so the equality doesn't make sense unless both matrices are square. However, the equality doesn't generally hold in this case.

Let's see what happens if you also have, for two *square* matrices, $(AB)^T=A^TB^T$:
\begin{gather}
A^TB^T=B^TA^T\\
(A^TB^T)^T=(B^TA^T)^T\\
(B^T)^T(A^T)^T=(A^T)^T(B^T)^T\\
BA=AB
\end{gather}
Conversely, it's obvious that from $AB=BA$ you can deduce $(AB)^T=A^TB^T$.

So the equality you read in your instructions is wrong.